# How to change equalizer presets with Tasker?

Tags: tasker

I am not using a third party application downloaded on the Play Store, but the **Sound enhancement** menu that comes pre-installed on some devices (can be found on `Settings -> Equalizer` on *Play Music* for example).

What I want is a pop up menu where I can choose one of two equalizer presets when plugging in my headphones or earphones. I know how to do the event and menu parts, but can't find something relevant for the presets.

Answer (score 1):

If you use *Apex* or *Nova* launcher: they've an integrated "activity browser". Just long-press on an empty place of your homescreen, select to add an activity.

[image: Select activity]
<sup>Activity selector in *Apex Launcher* (click image for full size variant)</sup>

Browse to the sound app, and see what activities it offers. As those "preset selectors" must be available as "screen" to interact with the user, they should have declared an activity; with some luck they did so "publically", and then its listed here.

As you can see in above screenshot, there's not only the "descriptive name" displayed, but along with it the package name (if it's the app entry, as the first one in the screenshot: "LocMgrPD" = "com.android.logmgrpd") or the activity to call if it's an activity (second and third entries, e.g.).

Once you found the matching activity, you can use that to call it from *Tasker*.

Comment: I've found three activities, but they don't launch. Two spams `No packages identifier for ressource[...]` in the logs, the third redirect to one of the other two...

Comment: Sh*t. I know some activities expect parameters (and thus cannot be launched that way). But I don't remember a case like yours. Can you browse the `Manifest` of the app in question? You should have found the package name by now at least ;) When in doubt: there are several "manifest readers" on Play, see e.g. [ManifestViewer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ManifestViewer/jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer). I'm not a dev, so I don't know whether parameters are mentioned there.